# C++: I need help with directory navigation

Tags: c++, file-io, directory

So, I want to be ableto chdir into a directory, if it exists, if not make the directory. If I am already in the directory, I just don't need to do anything.

Example

```
if (cur_dir == "dir_name")
// do stuff
else if ("dir_name" not exist?)
   mkdir "dir_name"
   chdir "dir_name"
else
   chdir "dir_name"
```

I've been googling, I've come up with this so far:

```
if (chdir(Config::CONFIG_FOLDER_NAME) == 0)
{
    std::cout << "Network Config Directory not found...\n";
    std::cout << "Creating folder called " << Config::CONFIG_FOLDER_NAME << "\n";
    mkdir(Config::CONFIG_FOLDER_NAME, 0777);
}
```

I haven't yet found a way to check to see what the current directory is.. (not the full path, which is what I did find.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Boost, you can use [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html):

```
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

fs::path configFolder(Config::CONFIG_FOLDER_NAME);

// Check if the current directory isn't already config folder
if (!fs::equivalent(configFolder, fs::current_path())
{
    // Create config folder if it doesn't exist
    if (!fs::exists(configFolder))
       fs::create_directory(configFolder);

    // Change working directory to config folder
    fs::current_path(configFolder);
}
```

By the way, if you're just planning to read a config file, you shouldn't need to change the working directory. Just read directly, using an absolute path. In Boost.Filesystem, you'd do that this way:

```
fs::path configFilePath = configFolder;
configFilePath /= "config.file";

// read configFilePath
```

Comment: In addition to what @Boaz-Yaniv has said: to change path, its very simple `fs::path p = some_path; p = new_path;`. Here is the reference to Boost Filesystem (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html). Look into the link that says 'Path assignments' and 'Path modifiers'.

Comment: @yasouser: Forgot to add the all-important link, thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the full path, then just parse it and look at the last segment (the part after the last "/").

Answer (score 0):

I think [getcwd()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd) is what you need.